# How do I complete this explode & comparison query properly? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, query-builder

I'm trying to get this string of tags and iterate through it to get the respective tag's columns on another table:

1A-3,1-1,1-2,3-4,4-6,4-8,6-13,6-15,8-6,8-11,7A-4,7A-5,7A-6

Checks against:
[image]

```
    $ministry = AgencyLogin::find(196);
            $prefs = $ministry->Ministry_Preferences;
            $tags = explode(',', $prefs);
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $sub_categories[] = DB::table('descriptor')
                ->where('tag', $tag)
                ->select('subcategory', 'description')
                ->first();
            }
//dd($sub_categories);
return view('agencydash', compact('sub_categories'));
```

`dd($prefs)` prints the correct string. `$sub_categories[]` never converts to an actual array, so can't be parsed like one, and my limited experience in Laravel means I don't know how to turn a query like this into an array instead the current thing it is, an object.

`dd($sub_categories)` after I treat it as an object prints a single result which seems to be random:

```
{#262 ▼
  +"subcategory": "SUPPORT ROLE"
  +"description": "Project Management"
}
```

I've been teaching myself Laravel and php steadily, so problems like this open more questions then I can answer yet. 
Anybody know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you iterating through $tags and not using whereIn method and getting a whole collection of relevant rows?

```
$ministry = AgencyLogin::find(196);
        $prefs = $ministry->Ministry_Preferences;
        $tags = explode(',', $prefs);
        $sub_categories = DB::table('descriptor')
            ->whereIn('tag', $tags)
            ->get(['subcategory', 'description']);
//dd($sub_categories);
return view('agencydash', compact('sub_categories'));
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Coz I'm too noobish to know that was a thing. :,D :,D thanks. That solves it.

Comment: @Mugluck glad I could help :) P.S. Don't forget to remove $sub_categories=[] or something, you had to define somewhere.